# Coherence requirements for laser as an optical oscillator

Tags: laser

Lasers are popularly described as coherent light sources, but it seems to me that there are several different concepts or levels of coherence that need to be distinguished.  (1) Same electronic or vibrational transition, (2) single rotational substate (in a gas), (3) single transverse cavity mode, and (4) single longitudinal cavity mode.

Levels (1-3) are pretty routine, but I should think that only (4) is suitable for optical oscillators used for interferometry and coherent (i.e., doppler) radar applications, which demand phase stability.

I am aware that etalons are used to separate and select one spectral line, but only at the price of discarding the power in unwanted spectral lines.  This can’t be much of a problem in doppler-broadened gas lasers, where there are only a few cavity resonances within the gain bandwidth, unless the cavity is a few meters long; but it must be a serious problem in solid-state lasers, where there are >10^4 lines within the gain bandwidth of the pumped medium.  What is the trick to make solid-state oscillators efficient, so that they don’t have to discard >99.99% of the power?

I am aware that homogeneous broadening (e.g., due to collisions) does not invite hole-burning, so all the excess energy in the population inversion could in principle be extracted.  But don’t all real solid-state materials suffer from inhomogeneous broadening (e.g., due to impurities) as well?

Comment: Re, "etalons...select one spectral line, but only at the price of discarding power..." Remember that the laser medium amplifies by stimulated emission. That is, it only amplifies wavelengths that are already present in the cavity. When the etalon is placed _in the cavity_, it suppresses undesirable wavelengths _before_ they get amplified, so not as much power is wasted as you might think.

Comment: I’m not entirely clear on what is the question. Is this about inhomogeneous broadening, single-mode laser design, or coherence in a broader sense?

Comment: @james large    I agree with your argument, but as I understand things, if *inhomogeneous* broadening is at work, none of the energy at wavelengths rejected by the etalon can be extracted because they just don't get amplified.  They won't corrupt the spectral purity of the output, but their energy is still wasted.

Comment: @Gilbert I know a list of tricks that can be used to enforce single-mode operation. I am asking how much energy in the pumped medium inevitably goes to waste because of inhomogeneous broadening, and how to minimize that waste.